# Texttrimming in Auto grid column

Tags: wpf

I want something very simple in WPF, but I don't get it to work:

I have a grid with 2 columns: one * and one Auto. The second column contains a TextBlock. I need texttrimming to work with this TextBlock. This doesn't work currently, because the TextBlock goes outside the bounds of the grid.

Extra info:

- The second column should be juste wide enough to contain the TextBlock. The first column should contain all remaining space. If the Grid isn't wide enough to contain the desired width of the TextBlock, the text should be trimmed.
- The width of the Grid changes when resizing the window.
- Nothing is static (not the text, no sizes), so hardcoded values can not be used.
- ClipToBounds property doesn't fix this issue.
- I can't bind MaxWidth of the TextBlock to the width of the column, otherwise the TextBlock will only getting smaller, but never bigger when resizing the window.

Code to reproduce the issue (for example in Kaxaml):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <DockPanel>
      <Grid Height="20" Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="100 0 100 0">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="200"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock
            Grid.Column="1"
            Background="Red"
            Text="Test tralalalalalalalalalala long string this should be trimmed!"
            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
      </Grid>
   </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second solution:
Use a Converter like this:

```
namespace StackStuff{

class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is Double)
        {
            return (double)value - 200; // 200 = 100+100 form the grid margin
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

In the View, you will have:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackStuff"
```

Then, you have to add the converter for it to be used:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then you have to implement  the converter:

```
<DockPanel Background="Green" x:Name="dock">
        <Grid Height="20" Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="100 0 100 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, ElementName=dock}"
                       Grid.Column="1"
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Then the textblock won't resize anymore when the window resizes: the column will stay the same width because the textblock stays the same width, because the column stays the same width...

Comment: you are right @Lander. try this fix, in your original post: 
`<ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="200"/>`
It has * instead of Auto on the second columndefinition

Comment: Adding a fixed MaxWidth on the Auto column will fix the issue. Problem: everything is dynamic, so I can't use fixed values.

Comment: Adding * instead of auto, works even if you do not use MaxWidth.

Comment: But then the width of the grid will just be devided by the two columns. I need the second column to be just wide enough to fit the TextBlock. If not enough space is available, the TextBlock should use up all space and use text trimming.

Comment: @Lander, I have edited my first answer, to give you another solution, after your details in the comment.

Comment: OK this works in my test setup and I could adapt this solution to my real world application, which is a bit more complex, but I could use the same idea: binding the MaxWidth of the TextBlock (not the column!) to the maximum size this column will be (so the size at which it should start trimming instead of getting bigger). Thanks!

Comment: I've never been able to come up with a robust, general-purpose solution for this problem. What I usually wind up doing is setting MaxWidth on the TextBlock instead of on the Grid or its parent panel. This works well enough as long as the TextBlock is the only variable-width element in the grid, which it usually is. It does make it harder to exert fine control over the Grid's width, though.